# MULTITHREADING c - read several files in the same file

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm new at multithreading and I'm trying to simulate banking transactions on the same  current account using multithreading.
Each thread reads the actions to perform from a file. The file will contain an operation for each line consisting of an integer. The main program have to create as many threads as files in the path.

```
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){

  DIR *buff;
struct dirent *dptr = NULL;
pthread_t hiloaux[MAX_THREADS];     
int  i=0,j=0, nthreads=0;
char *pathaux;


memset(hiloaux,0,sizeof(pthread_t)*MAX_THREADS);
diraux=malloc((267+strlen(argv[1]))*sizeof(char));
buff=opendir(argv[1]);
while((dptr = readdir(buff)) != NULL && nthreads<MAX_THREADS)//read files in the path
    {


    if (dptr->d_name[0]!='.'){    
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_path);//mutual exclusion  
        strcpy(pathaux,argv[1]);        
        strcat (pathaux,"/");
        strcat (pathaux,dptr->d_name);//makes the route (ex:path/a.txt)

        pthread_create(&hiloaux[nthreads],NULL,readfile,(void *)pathaux);
        //creates a thread for each file in the path
                   nthreads++;
    }

}

for (j=0;j<nthreads;j++){
pthread_join(hiloaux[j],NULL);
}

  closedir(buff);
  return 0;

}
```

My problem is that the threads don't seem to receive the correct path argument. Even though I have placed a mutex, (mutex_path) they all read the same file. I unlock this mutex inside the function readfile(), .

```
void *readfile(void *arg){
FILE *fichero;
int x=0,n=0;
int suma=0; 
int cuenta2=0;


char * file_path = (char*)arg;
n=rand() % 5+1; //random number to sleep the program each time I read a file line
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_path);//unlock the mutex

fichero = fopen(file_path, "r");

    while (fscanf (fichero, "%d", &x)!=EOF){

           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);//mutual exclusion to protect variables(x,cuenta,cuenta2)        

         cuenta2+=x;    

          if (cuenta2<0){
        printf("count discarded\n");
          }

          else cuenta=cuenta2;      
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);

    printf("sum= %d\n",cuenta);
    sleep(n); //Each time i read a line,i sleep the thread and let other thread read other fileline
}
 pthread_exit(NULL);
fclose(fichero);
```

}
When I run the program i get this output

```
alberto@ubuntu:~/Escritorio/practica3$ ./ejercicio3 path
read file-> path/fb
read -> 2
sum= 2
read file-> path/fb
read -> 2
sum= 2
read file-> path/fb
read -> 4
sum= 6
read file-> path/fb
read -> 4
sum= 6
read file-> path/fb
read -> 6
sum= 12
read file-> path/fb
read -> 6
sum= 12
```

It seems to work well, it reads a line and sleeps for a time, during this time another thread do its work, but the problem is that both threads open the same file (path/fb).
As i said before i think the problem is in path argument, is like the mutex_path did not make his work. 
I would really appreciate a little help with this, as I don't really know what's wrong.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "readfile" function

the line

char * file_path = (char*)arg;

Just copies a pointer the string memory but not the memory itself.
So it can (and will) still be altered by the man thread while worker thread continues.

Make a memory copy there.

Or even better store all arguments to your threads in distinct memory in main thread already, so you wont need the first mutex at all.

Answer (score 0):

First I do not see where u assign memory for pathaux. I am wondering how come strcpy or strcat is working rather than memory segmentation. Try compiling with C++ compiler and it may complain.

As to the problem u are passing the pointer, so every thread points to same location. 
Correct approach would be inside readdir loop -
1. create memory and copy the path to it.(Note u want to create memory every time in loop)
2. pass this memory to new thread. 
If you do this way :
a. you do not have to use mutex path.
b. call free at end of readfile method.